# Content Localization Domain Best Practices

Tags: language-agnostic, localization, seo, subdomain, currency

Unsure of the best way to go about localization of a site, looking for general feedback and best practises for a few headaches.

**Current Situation**

We have a store that needs to show different products based on user location (we only have the rights to sell certain products in certain locations), and different prices (based on the users local currency).

The issue that I'm currently facing is that the content is all of the same language (English), eventually this will be translated for each country and different language of content will be displayed based on the users locale and preferences.

The current plan is to route the user to a relavant sub-domain based upon location:

- `fr.domain.com` for `France` prices in `EUR`
- `de.domain.com` for `Germany` prices in `EUR`
- `it.domain.com` for `Italy` prices in `EUR`
- `us.domain.com` for `United States` prices in `USD`
- `gb.domain.com` for `United Kingdom` prices in `GBP`

and so on...

As the content is all of the same language, does this lead to a bad user experience (does `fr.domain.com` infer language (ie. French) as currently all the content will be in English). — Are there any SEO advantages/ disadvantages to this method? (Possible duplicated content issue if the same product, in the same language is listed on `it.domain.com` and `fr.domain.com`.

Or is this being completely over-thought, and until the content is translated into each language we should just use `domain.com`, detect user location and show relavant products and currencies based upon that.

Comment: FYI, "fr.domain.com" doesn't usually mean "France", but rather "French language".  So expect visitors from Switzerland, Quebec, Haiti, _etc._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do multilingual SEO on big sites every day, and this is exactly what I would do:

- Firstly, go with the subdomain structure. This is for one reason - you can more easily deal with subdomains than folders in Google Webmaster Tools and you can individually target each subdomain with the localisation feature; not possible with folders (well, it is, but it can cause various problems.)

The FYI given by Ross Patterson is true as default, but can be overridden and dealt with by Google Webmaster Tools as just mentioned and implementing the following:

- Secondly, implement rel=alternate hreflang tags as seen at

  http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077

This will deal with the duplicate content issues. I'd recommend the sitemap format rather than on-page code / header responses as I've found that to be much easier to maintain over time (the less external multinational stuff is dependent on the codebase, the better.)

- Lastly, get localised, natively translated content further down the line. It's the only way to make your site perform.

Answer (score 0):

Sub domains should not have a negative effect on SEO, normally its only the TLD (example.fr) that would effect SEO.

What's your idea around the sub-domain? Just for the sake of a clean URL? why not example.com/fr - example.com/en?

Comment: Idea behind the subdomain is as an alternative to domain.com/fr it would take us days to execute on fr.domain.com and weeks to execute on domain.com/fr. I gather the directory approach is the best in SEO terms. — I was just curious as to if xx.domain.com would have a negative SEO effect.

Comment: Well the directory method (example.com/fr example.com/us etc) would mean your main domain contains many more links / pages -> thus better for SEO.